# How to delete lines with same middle block?

Tags: shell, replace, awk, sed

This is probably an easy question for command-line ninjas, but I can't figure it out for the life of me. As of now, I'm using a PHP script to accomplish this, but I need to do it using awk/sed/cut or similar.

I have got a log file like this:

```
123 | foo | 12.13
756 | bar | 14.25
236 | baz | 11.23
536 | foo  | 10.13
947 | bar | 34.25
134 | baz | 11.26
```

I need to delete all lines that has the middle element same. If there *is* a duplicate, the newer version needs to be kept.  The output of the file after the removal should look like:

```
536 | foo  | 10.13
947 | bar | 34.25
134 | baz | 11.26
```

I'm new to this and have no idea how to do this, so a little nudge in the right direction would be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ tac file | awk -F' +[|] +' '!seen[$2]++' | tac
536 | foo  | 10.13
947 | bar | 34.25
134 | baz | 11.26
```

or if you prefer an awk-only solution:

```
$ awk -F' +[|] +' 'NR==FNR{fnr[$2]=FNR; next} FNR==fnr[$2]' file file
536 | foo  | 10.13
947 | bar | 34.25
134 | baz | 11.26
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `awk` command using a custom field separator:

```
awk -F' *\\| *' '!data[$2]{a[++k]=$2} {data[$2]=$0} 
           END{for (i=1; i<=k; i++) print data[a[i]]}' file
536 | foo  | 10.13
947 | bar | 34.25
134 | baz | 11.26
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the output order

```
perl -F'\s*\|\s*' -lanE '$s{$F[1]}=$_}{say $s{$_} for keys %s' <ca.txt
```

prints

```
134 | baz | 11.26
947 | bar | 34.25
536 | foo  | 10.13
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e ":a
$ !{N;ba
   }
:b
s/[0-9]* | \([^ ]*\) | [0-9.]*\n\(.*\)\1/\2\1/g
t b" YourFile
```

sed posix version (so `--posix` for GNU sed especially due to use of `|` inside `s///`)